# Not able to compile any c++ program in Linux using gcc, getting some weird error

Tags: c++, gcc

Recently I ran a code, to change the color of the output in the terminal. After running that c++ program, now if I run any c++ program in Linux I am getting some weird errors. I have attached the error picture.

[image: ERROR PIC]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share the source code that is generating the error along with the command you are using to compile it.

Comment: Use `g++` instead of `gcc`. The latter is for C, not C++.

Comment: The rules [require](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2752075) posting text as text, not as screenshots. Suggest doing that next time.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be trying to link a C++ program with gcc, which does not automatically link against the C++ standard library.  Try using g++ instead.